# Why are my compilations executed in the parent of `default-directory`?

Tags: compilation, directories

When I run `compile`, I'm seeing a strange behavior where the shell command is being executed in the parent of `default-directory` rather than `default-directory` itself. Here's an example of what I'm doing:

`(let ((default-directory "~/projects"))
  (compile "pwd"))`

And here's what shows up in the `*compilation*` buffer:

`-*-mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/projects/" -*-
Compilation started at Sun Jan 18 14:03:45
pwd
/Users/sixtynorth
Compilation finished at Sun Jan 18 14:03:45`

As you can see, on the first line of `*compilation*` the `default-directory` is correct. But when `pwd` actually executes I've been changed to the parent directory. This behavior seems consistent across different directories, commands, etc.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on? I've poked through the `compile` code, but nothing looks suspicious. I've also looked in my shell configuration for anything that might be causing problems, but again nothing jumped out at me. Any thoughts or ideas would be great.

Comment: FWIW, this occurs with a completely empty `.emacs`. This is on OSX. emacs-version reports "GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) of 2014-12-15 on achewood.local".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `default-directory` has to end with a slash.

Comment: heh...yep, it even says it right there in the documentation. I must have read past that 100 times. Thanks!